# On a JQuery page is JQuery a better way to display/hide an element than Javascript on its own?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I've already loaded jquery for lots of other stuff (i.e. I've already incurred the overhead of loading jquery).

With that in mind is there a 'right' way of showing/hiding elements - is either of these two 'better' or 'more efficient' than the other?

**JAVASCRIPT-ONLY:**

```
document.getElementById('stuff').style.display = 'none';
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$jsjp('#stuff').css('display','block');
```

Thanks!

Comment: The advantage of JQery is that the usibility is more comfortable than plain javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript will most always be faster than jQuery, just for the fact that jQuery (generally) introduces at least one additional layer of call to what could have been native otherwise.

But consider, at least in the context of your question, how you'd hide an element in native JS:

```
foo.style.display = 'none';
```

as compared to jQuery:

```
foo.hide();
```

Not much difference, and save for character count, there's really nothing much to go on.

Now, let's reverse that. How would you go about displaying `foo` back in jQuery?

```
foo.show();
```

and in raw JS:

```
foo.style.display = 'block';
```

Done. Not much difference as well.

Or is there? Take a second to think about that a bit. Our first problem here really is *how we got to the assumption that we're setting `display = 'block'` in the first place*. Should we set `foo` to a block display? Shouldn't it be an `inline` instead? Or an `inline-block`?

Most of the time, you'll have nothing to go on with deciding which to use, and if on the off chance that you do, you probably wrote some backing code to make sure you did.

One of the primary (often overlooked) benefits to jQuery's implementation of `show` and `hide` is that all that tracking is done silently for you. If you called `.hide()` on a block element, once you call `.show()` on it, jQuery will put it back to block, and not anything else.

Whatever you decide to go on with your question, make sure you consider this as well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give the description

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JavaScript is always faster than jQuery, but as the jQuery for ID selectors uses native `getElementById` function, there is no main difference between the two, you can also use `show` and `hide` methods:

```
$jsjp('#stuff').hide()
```

Comment: not least, you should use `.hide()` because it'll automatically set the `display` attribute to its original value when you call `.show()`, and not assume that it was `block`, `inline`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `$('#stuff').hide()`| `$('#stuff').show()` instead of `$('#stuff').css('display','none');` | `$('#stuff').css('display','block');`

Comment: using 'display:block' is connected to the '.show()' function ;-)

Comment: @reporter that is incorrect. as pointed elsewhere `show` will try to restore the _previous_ display state, not necessarily block. Check the `showHide` function in the source http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js

Comment: @Ben reporters point was that `.hide()` is the _opposite_ of `display: block`

Comment: @AntonWestberg you've still got your two examples the wrong way around.